# Component tests failing even i skipped them in pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, junit

I am facing below issue since a week and Even when i skipped my component tests its still failing when i run the build. I tried my level best to resolve this issue but still i am facing same below issue, Can some one help me to resolve this issue?.

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spock-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.3-groovy-4.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-rxjava-2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230618</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-junit4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-templates</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions><!-- https://www.baeldung.com/maven-version-collision -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>opt/ajsc/etc/config</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                    <include>**/*.cfg</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>WirelessOrderMs</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**resources/swagger/*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                        <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                        <useModulePath>false</useModulePath> <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1809 -->
                        <useFile>false</useFile>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/contract/*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/integration/*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/component/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
                <build.profile.id>local</build.profile.id>
                <skipITs>true</skipITs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

### issue

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.<init>(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:149)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.createTestSpecification(RestAssured.java:1453)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.given(RestAssured.java:654)
    at com.att.idp.wireless.order.component.BaseCompTest.givenBaseSpec(BaseCompTest.java:76)
    at com.att.idp.wireless.order.component.TaxResourceCompTest.checkCalculateTax_success(TaxResourceCompTest.java:67)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at 

[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   Click2StoreResourceCompTest.getDevAvailability_fail_400_InvalidRequest:109->BaseCompTest.givenBaseSpec:76 » AbstractMethod Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
[ERROR]   Click2StoreResourceCompTest.getDevAvailability_fail_400_InvalidRequestWithCartMode:184->BaseCompTest.givenBaseSpec:76 » AbstractMethod Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
[ERROR]   Click2StoreResourceCompTest.getDevAvailability_success:92->BaseCompTest.givenBaseSpec:76 » AbstractMethod Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
[ERROR]   Click2StoreResourceCompTest.getDevAvailability_successWithCartMode:148->BaseCompTest.givenBaseSpec:76 » AbstractMethod Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
[ERROR]   Click2StoreResourceCompTest.getSDDAvailability_fail_500_InvalidRequestWithCartMode:236->BaseCompTest.givenBaseSpec:76 » AbstractMethod Receiver class io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
```